# MS Access Database Corruption when users fill field manually

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

The situation with MS Access 2016:

- We have a front end with around 5-10 active users simultaneously, locally on their pc.
- The front end is linked to the back end being 20 tables divided in 5 databases stored on a local server
- The front end contains a lot of functions as well as manual inputs through forms
- (It is an engineering assistance tool running a lot of VBA, Shells and API, however this issue seems pure MS Access related)

Basically, the issue is that when users fill in data "directly" to the table (Through a form view), the database get corrupted. This happens when the user wants to fill in a lot of fields after one another, filling in very fast. The task could be: "1","ArrowDown",",1","ArrowDown" etc. This will most certainly corrupt the database.

[image: Example of manual fields]

I'm looking for a solution of how to minimize the risk of corrupting the database. Using functions, SQL and VBA to fill fields is not a good solution for this particular issue. If you need elaboration, please ask, and I will update the question.

BR, Emil

EDIT: Query SQL as requested:

```
SELECT t_ProjectComponents.ID, t_ProjectComponents.CNG, t_Components_1.Description, t_Components.[CNA?], t_ProjectComponents.[Project Quantity] AS Qty, t_ProjectComponents.CN, t_Components_1.DrawNrManuCode, t_Components.Description, t_Components.Manufacturer, t_Components.DrawNrManuCode, Round([t_Components].[Price]/[forms]![f_Main_Projects]![txt_exchange],2) & IIf([t_components]![Price]>0," " & Currency_Saved_Str_Pub(),"") AS [Current Unit Price], t_ProjectComponents.[Approved for Purchase], t_ProjectComponents.Terminated, t_ProjectComponents.SparePart, t_ProjectComponents.[Purchase Date], t_ProjectComponents.[Purchased by], t_Components.CS, t_Components.Group, t_Components.[Old ID], t_ProjectComponents.FinalPart, t_Components.Datasheet, t_ProjectComponents.Comment, t_Components.SerialReq, t_Components.BatchReq, t_Components.Vendor, t_Components.[Vendor Number], t_Components.Comment, t_Components.[Approved for Use]
FROM t_Components AS t_Components_1 RIGHT JOIN (t_ProjectComponents INNER JOIN t_Components ON t_ProjectComponents.CN = t_Components.CN) ON t_Components_1.CN = t_ProjectComponents.CNG
WHERE (((t_ProjectComponents.CNG) Like IIf(IsNull([forms]![f_Main_Projects]![txt_CNGnumberProject]),"*",[forms]![f_Main_Projects]![txt_CNGnumberProject])) AND ((t_Components_1.Description) Like "*" & [forms]![f_Main_Projects]![txt_Description] & "*") AND ((t_ProjectComponents.CN) Like IIf(IsNull([forms]![f_Main_Projects]![txt_CNnumberProject]),"*",[forms]![f_Main_Projects]![txt_CNnumberProject])) AND ((t_Components_1.DrawNrManuCode) Like IIf(IsNull([forms]![f_Main_Projects]![txt_AssDraw]),"*",[forms]![f_Main_Projects]![txt_AssDraw])) AND ((t_Components.Description) Like "*" & [forms]![f_Main_Projects]![txt_descriptionProject] & "*") AND ((t_Components.Manufacturer) Like "*" & [forms]![f_Main_Projects]![combo_brandProject] & "*") AND ((t_Components.DrawNrManuCode) Like IIf(IsNull([forms]![f_Main_Projects]![txt_specsProject]),"*",[forms]![f_Main_Projects]![txt_specsProject])) AND ((t_Components.[Old ID]) Like "*" & [forms]![f_Main_Projects]![txt_OldId] & "*")) OR (((t_ProjectComponents.CNG) Is Null)) OR (((t_Components_1.Description) Is Null)) OR (((t_ProjectComponents.CN) Is Null)) OR (((t_Components_1.DrawNrManuCode) Is Null)) OR (((t_Components.Description) Is Null)) OR (((t_Components.Manufacturer) Is Null)) OR (((t_Components.DrawNrManuCode) Is Null)) OR (((t_Components.[Old ID]) Is Null))
ORDER BY t_ProjectComponents.CNG, t_ProjectComponents.CN;
```

Comment: Is this the form all 5-10 users can view at the same time? Is there a "work queue" that divides the queue on the form above to different users and not duplicating?

Comment: There is no work queue. But, the database corruption occurs also when only 1 user has this database/table open. Basically when 1 user is filling in data fast.

Comment: The speed of filling in data does not effect the tables and cause corruptions. Is there another form open behind this form (or a subform) that has the exact same data visible? Is there an AfterUpdate event that fires when a users leaves the record?

Comment: @Chris There is OnLoad and OnClick event for the front end. No other form is showing the "WP" and "Supply from?" column. However, the "Description" and other fields are from another table, but these are all locked. Only local fields with no links are open for manual edit.

Comment: Then the issue is 2 or more people are updating the same record at the same time. The speed is playing a factor in it because if person A is faster then person B and catches up to the same record. I would think about creating another form that the users navigate to in order to make edits to specific records 1 at a time, or build a form that doesn't show them the queue but gives them 1 record at a time for the users to make updates to. You can go as far as making it random or choosing the record from top to bottom.

Comment: @Chris I think the issue is present even with only 1 person "online". At least I have been told by the user that no one else was a work at the time of the error. I will have to dig into that if that is the obvious explanation. But I don't see how to avoid it? 2 users could navigate to that "another form" and enter data. And, btw, we have a lot of other fields, filled by users through VBA and SQL, at the same time, without any corruption :(

Comment: These columns seem to be on the "many" side of a one-to-many relation. Does this table have a Primary key? Is it part of the form's record source? If no, try adding it. Also for testing, make it a visible (but locked) column in the form. Or at least an invisible field on the form (detail section).

Comment: Also you may want to think about moving to SQL Server Express as backend.

Comment: @Andre Yes all tables has Primary key and there are no dublicates. That part should be flawless (i hope). I dont understand your comment about "one-to-many" relation, can you elaborate.
I am thinking about changing backend. I would like something online that works similar to an access database on a local server. Any suggestions? (Off topic).

Comment: Do you have the code in your back end that allows you to run and see all current connections to the back end? even though only 1 person could be at work, another user could of left for the day, leaving the database open and a record in edit mode.

Comment: I have a script that shows how many online users - I can check that. I can kick everyone out as well and test it asap. I will get back to you when i have run a solo test.

Comment: I assume your form record source is a query. Please add the SQL of the query to your question.

Comment: And a very different question: what **exactly** do you mean by "corruption"? And how do you solve it at the moment?

Comment: @Andre Just added the SQL to the question. It's not small... By corruption i mean that the database wont open and it need to repair itself through MS Access. That works fine - The problem is we have to cut off all users to do so, and since it happens every other day, it's a bit of a pain in the a**.